# What is the proper way to pass dynamically allocated pointers to pthreads

Tags: c, multithreading, pointers, pthreads

I'm writing a program for an assignment to perform matrix multiplication using pthreads. It works by specifying the matrix size, *n*, (matrices are assumed to be square) and the number of threads, *p*, which is assumed to divide *n* evenly. For **A** x **B**, **A** is partitioned horizontally into *p* segments and each thread receives as input a single segment and the entire matrix **B** and returns a portion of the resultant matrix **C**.

The problem I'm having is not really to do with the assignment itself but a more general issue on the nature of pthreads that I haven't been able to find an answer to. I'll try to strip it back as much as possible. My matrices are stored as 1D arrays inside a struct.

```
typedef struct matrix {
    int *matrix;
    int size;
} matrix_t
```

They are allocated like so

```
matrix_t mtx = {
    malloc(input_size * input_size * sizeof(int)),
    input_size
};
```

and populated randomly by a function. The partitions are stored in a 2D array, the address of which is returned from a function but allocated like so in the normal way:

```
int **partitions = partitionmtx(mtx, num_threads);

int **partitionmtx(matrix_t mtx, int threads) 
{
    int partlen = mtx.size * (mtx.size / threads);
    int **parts = malloc(threads * sizeof(int));

    for(int i = 0; i < threads; ++i) {
        parts[i] = malloc(partlen * sizeof(int));
        // partitions populated...
    }

    return parts;
}
```

This works fine. The problem comes in when I send each partition off to a thread. In order to keep the arguments to the thread simple, I've bundled them like so:

```
typedef struct operand {
    matrix_t matrix;
    int *partition;
    int partition_length;
} operand_t;
```

I'm creating the pthreads like so:

```
pthread_t threads[num_threads];
pthread_mutex_init(&mymutex, NULL);
int rc;

for(int i = 0; i < num_threads; ++i) {
    operand_t op = {matrix, partitions[i], partition_length};
    rc = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, partition_product, (void *)&op);
    assert(rc == 0);
}

for(int i = 0; i < num_threads; ++i) {
    rc = pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
    assert(rc == 0);
}
```

Moving over to my function partition_product. My first priority was obviously making sure every thread was getting the correct data so I printed what each thread had like so:

```
void* partition_product(void *args)
{
    operand_t *op = (operand_t *)args;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mymutex);

    printf("Matrix:\n);
    printmtx(op->matrix); // This is a function I defined but its details aren't relevant here
    printf("\nPartition:" );
    for(int i = 0; i < op->partition_length; ++i)
        printf("%4d", op->partition[i]);

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mymutex);
}
```

This is where my problem came in. The matrices print from the threads with no problem. The problem is that all the threads, once I specify more than one thread, e.g.

```
./threadmatrix -n 4 -p 4
```

all printed the same partition. I thought this might have been a side effect of printing from threads, hence the mutex lock on prints. I thought then to print the address of each partitions[i] in the original thread and in the created threads to see what was happening, and it seems each thread is receiving the same address from the point of creation. I'm getting data into the threads and seem to be able to manipulate it without issue, but it's all the same data. Specifically, they always get the address of the last partition. I've tried all the good pointer practice I know and still if partitions[i] has address 0x00007ffffde234, say, then all 4 threads from the above invocation print address 0x00007ffffde234. I've searched high and low for some explanation and found nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: OT: regarding  `assert(rc == 0);`  This will only cause the program to (crash/exit)  and should not be in production code.  Suggest using: `if( ( rc = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, partition_product, (void *)&op) != 0) { perror( "pthread_create failed" ); followed by cleanup activities followed by `exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }`  `perror()`  will output your error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`  .  This is much more informative to the user than just crashing the program via `assert()`

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is here:

```
operand_t op = {matrix, partitions[i], partition_length};
rc = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, partition_product, (void *)&op);
```

Note that the pointer you are passing in the last argument is a pointer to `op`, which is located on the stack.  The problem with that is that as soon as the main thread completes its iteration of its for-loop, `op` is going to be destroyed, and then recreated for the next iteration of the loop; which means that later on, when the child thread starts running and tries to use that pointer-argument, the `operand_t` that the pointer points to will no longer be valid.   (In your case, the same stack-memory location is being re-used for all of the created child threads, which partially explains the behavior you are seeing)

To avoid that problem, you need to make sure that the lifetime of the object that you pass a pointer to is long enough that the object will still be valid when the child thread dereferences the pointer to read the fields of the object.  The easiest way to do that is to allocate the object on the heap, instead:

```
operand_t * op = (operand_t *) malloc(sizeof(operand_t));
op->matrix = matrix;
op->partition = partitions[i];
op->partition_length = partition_length;
rc = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, partition_product, (void *)op);
```

The only (small) catch is that your child thread will now be responsible for calling `free` on the `operand_t *` it receives, after it is done using that object; otherwise the memory will be leaked.

Comment: That solved it! Thank you so much I have been pulling my hair out over this since yesterday afternoon. It never even crossed my mind that the parent will have overwritten the data by the time the child is accessing it. It seems I have a lot to used to with multithreading.